# "recipient" of the message in near protocol signMessage function

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to authenticate account in backend for NEAR protocol

Referring this doc:
https://docs.near.org/develop/integrate/backend-login#2-ask-the-user-to-sign-the-challenge

```
const signature = wallet.signMessage({ message, recipient, nonce: challenge, callbackUrl: <server-auth-url> })
```

but I haven't understood what to put in recipient and why it is used for